# std::string or char[] as the element for a large array-like structure

Tags: c++, string

I'm creating a hash table. Each value is a string. I have the problem of deciding what structure to use to store the string. Intuitively I thought of `std::string` and `char*`. But,

1), `std::string` seems to use the stack if the string is short. That means it's not a good choice if my hash table is really big.
2), If using `char*` then I don't know what to return if I want to change a value, for example like in the following situation: `myTable[i] = changedString;` It seems in this case I'll need to implement a new string class. But I'm feeling it won't be necessary with `std::string` there.

Could anyone give any suggestions/comments? Thanks!

Comment: _"std::string seems to use the stack if the string is short"_. How should it use stack if you are going to store them in a `unordered_map<K,V>`? I'd say, stick with string until you verify there is any problem with that.

Comment: emm I'm implementing my own hash table. But maybe I'll stick to std::string now. Thanks~

Comment: Use neither. Instead have a template parameter to let the user of the table pass use any string class

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are trying to implement unordered_map (H.W?) and that this is why you dont use it.

you should use std::vector, or std::string, but don't use the array.

And why is there problem of std::string using a stack?

Comment: I think he meant "short string optimization". One of the stdlib implementations statically allocates an array of 19 characters for short strings.

Comment: Oh there's no specific reason of std::string using a stack. I think it's because I don't have much experience judging how to arrange the memory. Because I learned 'stack has a limited size and is for temporary variables', I kinda want to leave it for local small value-based variables and design most of my complex structures using the heap. Don't know how to decide what's better/necessary..

Comment: @flyinggip You should not concern yourself with that, and you are talking about the runtime-stack, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack. The ADT stack is not limited on size - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type), as for what std::string uses internally, it should not concern you, nor you should count on it as it is a compiler specification. The public API  string has is the same for all implementation and string sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead caused by `std::string` is minimal, actually AFAIK apart from the pointer to the string's internal buffer, there are just `size` and `capacity` members, both of type `size_t`, causing let's say (it's environment dependent) 8 bytes per string, so if you have an array of 100 000 strings, there would be about 780KB overhead, which is something I wouldn't worry about unless you are in an environment with strict memory limitations.

In case the length of the string is fixed or varies in minimal way (let's say 2 to 4 characters), then it could be more reasonable to use an array with automatic storage duration:

```
struct X {
    ...
    char code[4]; // up to 4 characters
};
```

which would work fine even while copying instances of it in a following way:

```
X x1, x2;
...
x2 = x1;
```

However in case you don't have a really good reason to worry about this right now, anything you'd do at this point is pretty much a ***premature optimization***.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I think one day I'll come back to the examples again.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create a hash table, you should try to eliminate any distractions that would make that specific task more complicated.  As such you should use std::string for the mutable values in your table so you don't have to spend development effort on allocating and deallocating char*

Once your hash table is functional and correct, if you have a reason to move to char*, then you can always change to that later on.  Focus on your highest priority goal, the hash table, and don't spend time on trying to beat std::string performance until your first goal is reached; beating std::string may not be worthwhile in any case.

Comment: Thanks I think this quite fits my level of experience now. I'd vote it if I've got more reputation.